# Unable to upgrade swagger2 version from 2.7.0 to 3.00 in Spring REST API(regular Spring not sprint boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0, spring-rest

My project is working fine with swagger2 version 2.7.0.not spring boot(spring mvc only)
I am going to upgrade it 3.0.0 but it's giving plugin errors.

`java.lang.nosuchMethodError:org.springframework.plugin.core.pluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Optional;`

My config as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>


Update: As mentioned in https://github.com/springfox/springfox
Step 2 : Add @EnableOpenApi for open API (and @EnableSwagger2WebMvc or @EnableSwagger2WebFlux for older versions)
I added @EnableSwagger2WebMvc in class ,Then it's asking dependency of springfox-swagger2,
as this coming from :
http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/snapshot/springfox/documentation/swagger2/annotations/EnableSwagger2WebMvc.html 
which is part of springfox-swagger2 dependency

Hence I am confused what to do..
can you please help cleaner approach with steps .
If I don't  use @EnableSwagger2WebMvc/EnableSwagger2
Swagger is not getting loaded
```

Comment: Hi..All..any update on this issue?

Comment: Hi All any other way to do..not working

Comment: did you get it working finally ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using Spring Boot, or regular Spring flavor, but have you followed the migration instructions posted here?

https://github.com/springfox/springfox

1. Remove explicit dependencies on `springfox-swagger2`
2. Remove any `@EnableSwagger2...` annotations
3. Add the `springfox-boot-starter` (Spring boot) or `springfox-oas`(Spring MVC) dependency
4. Check if you do not rely on removed dependecy on `guava`
5. If you are using `WebMvc` but you don't use the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation yet, add this annotation (Spring boot).

Comment: i will check & let you know shortly

Comment: Remove explicit dependencies on springfox-swagger2...what is meaning...shall i remove dependency from pom.xml?

Comment: Correct, the tool is packaged under different maven coordinates.

Comment: If i remove <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>   getting compilation issue(import issue) as unable to found springfox/documentation/swagger2/annotations/EnableSwagger2WebMvc   where i am trying to use @EnableSwagger2WebMvc

Comment: See next step, step 2, then.

Comment: i am using spring ,not spring boot.so as per github link ,it's asking to add 
Add EnableOpenApi for open API (and EnableSwagger2WebMvc or @EnableSwagger2WebFlux for older versions)
if i do add EnableSwagger2WebMvc  it's asking for springfox-swagger2,which already removed in step 1